# Automatic conflict resolution on certain files (subversion)

Tags: svn, merge-conflict-resolution

I have a situation where makefiles are getting automatically updated as part of the build process, but still they are under subversion version control. (Yes I know you it's questionable put automatically created files under revision control, but this is the case nevertheless).

This results in that during `svn update` there will often be a conflict for the makefiles and in reality the resolution of taking "mine-full" or "theirs-full" is quite acceptable.

Now I would like to automate this, but I don't want a solution where I end up in automatic resolution for every file, but just those that matches a certain pattern (eg only those which are named `makefile`). Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not actually resolving merge conflicts you could solve the problem by avoiding the conflict by not having a modified copy of the makefiles. This can be done by reverting the changes before updating:

```
find -type f -name makefile -exec svn revert {} +
svn update
```

This will unconditionally take their full version (even if the changes could have been merged without conflict).